# Infinite from zero division

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, if you divide by `0` you get `Infinity`

```
typeof Infinity; //number
isNaN(Infinity); //false
```

This insinuates that Infinity is a number (of course, no argument there).

What I learned that anything divided by zero is in an indeterminate form and has no value, is not a number.

That definition however is for arithmetic, and I know that in programming it can either yield Infinity, Not a Number, or just throw an exception.

So why throw Infinity? Does anybody have an explanation on that?

Comment: I can understand a close vote, but at least close for the right reason.. this isn't "general computing or software" it's a specific question about JavaScript ;) Nor is it primarily opinion based... LOL infinity isn't an opinion xD

Comment: `Infinity/Infinity = 0/0 = NaN`, `Infinity/x = Infinity` and `x/Infinity = 0` seems quite reasonable.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question according to the FAQ - it has a proper and determinate answer (as you can see below) within the scope of SO (it's about a programming language!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, resulting in `Infinity` is not due to some crazy math behind the scenes.  [The spec states that](http://es5.github.io/#x11.5.2):

> Division of a non-zero finite value by a zero results in a signed infinity. The sign is determined by the rule already stated above.

The logic of the spec authors goes along these lines:

`2/1 = 2`.  Simple enough.

`2/0.5 = 4`.  Halving the denominator doubles the result.

...and so on:

`2/0.0000000000000005 = 4e+1`.  As the denominator trends toward zero, the result grows.  Thus, the spec authors decided for division by zero to default to Infinity, as well as any other operation that results in a number too big for JavaScript to represent [0].  (instead of some quasi-numeric state or a divide by zero exception).

You can see this in action in the code of Google's V8 engine: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/bd8c70f5fc9c57eeee478ed36f933d3139ee221a/src/hydrogen-instructions.cc#L4063

[0] "If the magnitude is too large to represent, the operation overflows; the result is then an infinity of appropriate sign."

Comment: This is mathematically incorrect. Division by zero does not *result in* the largest number imaginable, it simply *tends towards* that, when approaching it from the positive side.

Comment: True, but we're talking about *JavaScript*, not math.  There are differences imposed by reality.

Comment: To add to what @Joeytje50 said (which I agree with), even the notion of "tending to infinity" is not always valid. I can construct f(x) such that the limit of f(x)/x as x→0+ = z for any desired constant real number *z*.

Comment: @TypeIA sure, you can construct a function f(x)/x to approach any value as x approaches zero, but you can't with c/x where c is a constant. The key that makes this approach infinity is that the numerator doesn't change, which is what would need to be modeled for a simple division operation.

Answer (score 0):

When `x` tends towards 0 in the formula `y=1/x`, `y` tends towards infinity. So it would make sense if something that would end up as a really high number (following that logic)  would be represented by infinity. Somewhere around `10^320`, JavaScript returns `Infinity` instead of the actual result, so if the calculation would otherwise end up above that threshold, it just returns infinity instead.

Comment: Actually, no. Division by 0 returns `Infinity` without any arithmetic. http://es5.github.io/#x11.5.2

Comment: Fabrício is correct, this is not at all what actually happens.

Comment: The answer would be correct if the question was about dividing a very large number by a very small number, however dividing by 0 is mathematically impossible -- from my previous comment's link: "Division of a non-zero finite value by a zero results in a signed infinity". Maybe the division by zero return value was influenced by the overflow which may happen on certain divisions that also returns Infinity as you've described, but the actual reason for division by 0 to return Infinity is a clause in the spec.

Comment: Your rewrite is more coherent, I've removed my DV. Meh, I'll even throw an upvote since your answer explains the same point as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a loosely typed language which means that it doesn't have to return the type you were expecting from a function.

Infinity isn't actually an integer

In a strongly typed language if your function was supposed to return an int this means the only thing you can do when you get a value that isn't an int is to throw an exception

In loosely typed language you have another option which is to return a new type that represents the result better (such as in this case infinity)

Comment: typeof Infinity === "number"

Answer (score 0):

Infinity is very different than indetermination.

If you compute x/0+ you get +infinity and for x/o- you get -infinity (x>0 in that example).

Javascript uses it to note that you have exceeded the capacity of the underlaying floating point storage.

You can then handle it to direct your sw towards either exceptional cases or big number version of your computation.

Infinity is actually consistent in formulae. Without it, you have to break formulae into small pieces, and you end up with more complicated code.

Try this, and you get j as Infinity:

```
var i = Infinity;
var j = 2*i/5;
console.log("result = "+j);
```

Answer (score 0):

As determined by the [ECMAScript language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.5.2):

> The sign of the result is positive if both operands have the same
>   sign, negative if the operands have different signs.
>
> Division of an infinity by a zero results in an infinity. The sign is
>   determined by the rule already stated above.
>
> Division of a nonzero finite value by a zero results in a signed infinity. The sign is determined by the rule already stated above.

As the denominator of an arithmetic fraction tends towards `0` (for a finite non-zero numerator) the result tends towards `+Infinity` or `-Infinity` depending on the signs of the operands. This can be seen by:

- `1/0.1 = 10`
- `1/0.01 = 100`
- `1/0.001 = 1000`
- `1/0.0000000001 = 10000000000`
- `1/1e-308 = 1e308`

Taking this further then when you perform a division by zero then the JavaScript engine gives the result (as determined by the spec quoted above):

- `1/0 = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY`
- `-1/0 = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`
- `-1/-0 = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY`
- `1/-0 = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`

It is the same if you divide by a sufficiently large value:

- `1/1e309 = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY`

Answer (score 0):

This is because Javascript uses Floating point arithmetics and it's exception for handling division by zero.

> Division by zero (an operation on finite operands gives an exact infinite result, e.g., 1/0 or log(0)) (returns ±infinity by default).

[wikipedia source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)